# How to nest ngfor tables. Only able to show one nested property

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, ngfor

If in the second ngFor I only use subtask.taskID, everything works.  The second I include a second thing to be interpolated, namely subtask.taskName, it breaks.

If I comment out subtask.taskID and leave subtask.taskName, everything works. 
Why is this happening.  Why am I unable to display multiple subtasks in my second ngFor?

EDIT: similar problem.  can't get other properties of my subtasks to show.  I can only get one to display.  I've also updated the code, as I'm slowly working through this tree-grid component.  stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xk9nw6

```
<H1>Table</H1>

<table  class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>expand</th>
    <th>task id</th>
    <th>task name</th>
    <th>button</th>
  </tr>
</thead>  
<tbody *ngFor="let datum of data">
  <tr>
    <td class="" (click)="subtask(datum)">> </td>
    <td class="">{{datum.taskID}}</td>
    <td class="">{{datum.taskName}}</td>
    <td class="btn btn.primary" (click)="dropdown(datum)">...</td>
  </tr>
      <tr [hidden]="!foo" *ngFor="let subtask of datum.subtasks" >
          <td class="">> </td>
          <td class="">{{subtask?.taskID}}</td>
          <td class="">{{substask?.taskName}}</td>
          <td class=" btn btn.primary" (click)="dropdown(subtask)">...</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>  
 </table>
```

sample data

```
/**
 * Test cases data source
 */
export let sampleData: Object[] = [
    {
        taskID: 1,
        taskName: 'Planning',
        startDate: new Date('02/03/2017'),
        endDate: new Date('02/07/2017'),
        progress: 100,
        duration: 5,
        priority: 'Normal',
        approved: false,
        isInExpandState: true,
        subtasks: [
            { taskID: 2, taskName: 'Plan timeline', startDate: new Date('02/03/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/07/2017'), duration: 5, progress: 100, priority: 'Normal', approved: false },
            { taskID: 3, taskName: 'Plan budget', startDate: new Date('02/03/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/07/2017'), duration: 5, progress: 100, approved: true },
            { taskID: 4, taskName: 'Allocate resources', startDate: new Date('02/03/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/07/2017'), duration: 5, progress: 100, priority: 'Critical', approved: false },
            { taskID: 5, taskName: 'Planning complete', startDate: new Date('02/07/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/07/2017'), duration: 0, progress: 0, priority: 'Low', approved: true }
        ]
    },
    {
        taskID: 6,
        taskName: 'Design',
        startDate: new Date('02/10/2017'),
        endDate: new Date('02/14/2017'),
        duration: 3,
        progress: 86,
        priority: 'High',
        isInExpandState: false,
        approved: false,
        subtasks: [
            { taskID: 7, taskName: 'Software Specification', startDate: new Date('02/10/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/12/2017'), duration: 3, progress: 60, priority: 'Normal', approved: false },
            { taskID: 8, taskName: 'Develop prototype', startDate: new Date('02/10/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/12/2017'), duration: 3, progress: 100, priority: 'Critical', approved: false },
            { taskID: 9, taskName: 'Get approval from customer', startDate: new Date('02/13/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/14/2017'), duration: 2, progress: 100, approved: true },
            { taskID: 10, taskName: 'Design Documentation', startDate: new Date('02/13/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/14/2017'), duration: 2, progress: 100, approved: true },
            { taskID: 11, taskName: 'Design complete', startDate: new Date('02/14/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/14/2017'), duration: 0, progress: 0, priority: 'Normal', approved: true }
        ]
    },
    {
        taskID: 12,
        taskName: 'Implementation Phase',
        startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
        endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'),
        priority: 'Normal',
        approved: false,
        duration: 11,
        subtasks: [
            {
                taskID: 13,
                taskName: 'Phase 1',
                startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'),
                priority: 'High',
                approved: false,
                duration: 11,
                subtasks: [{
                    taskID: 14,
                    taskName: 'Implementation Module 1',
                    startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                    endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'),
                    priority: 'Normal',
                    duration: 11,
                    approved: false,
                    subtasks: [
                        { taskID: 15, taskName: 'Development Task 1', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/19/2017'), duration: 3, progress: '50', priority: 'High', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 16, taskName: 'Development Task 2', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/19/2017'), duration: 3, progress: '50', priority: 'Low', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 17, taskName: 'Testing', startDate: new Date('02/20/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/21/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Normal', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 18, taskName: 'Bug fix', startDate: new Date('02/24/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/25/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Critical', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 19, taskName: 'Customer review meeting', startDate: new Date('02/26/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'High', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 20, taskName: 'Phase 1 complete', startDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), duration: 0, priority: 'Low', approved: true }

                    ]
                }]
            },
            {
                taskID: 21,
                taskName: 'Phase 2',
                startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                endDate: new Date('02/28/2017'),
                priority: 'High',
                approved: false,
                duration: 12,
                subtasks: [{
                    taskID: 22,
                    taskName: 'Implementation Module 2',
                    startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                    endDate: new Date('02/28/2017'),
                    priority: 'Critical',
                    approved: false,
                    duration: 12,
                    subtasks: [
                        { taskID: 23, taskName: 'Development Task 1', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/20/2017'), duration: 4, progress: '50', priority: 'Normal', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 24, taskName: 'Development Task 2', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/20/2017'), duration: 4, progress: '50', priority: 'Critical', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 25, taskName: 'Testing', startDate: new Date('02/21/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/24/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'High', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 26, taskName: 'Bug fix', startDate: new Date('02/25/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/26/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Low', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 27, taskName: 'Customer review meeting', startDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/28/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Critical', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 28, taskName: 'Phase 2 complete', startDate: new Date('02/28/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/28/2017'), duration: 0, priority: 'Normal', approved: false }

                    ]
                }]
            },

            {
                taskID: 29,
                taskName: 'Phase 3',
                startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'),
                priority: 'Normal',
                approved: false,
                duration: 11,
                subtasks: [{
                    taskID: 30,
                    taskName: 'Implementation Module 3',
                    startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'),
                    endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'),
                    priority: 'High',
                    approved: false,
                    duration: 11,
                    subtasks: [
                        { taskID: 31, taskName: 'Development Task 1', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/19/2017'), duration: 3, progress: '50', priority: 'Low', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 32, taskName: 'Development Task 2', startDate: new Date('02/17/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/19/2017'), duration: 3, progress: '50', priority: 'Normal', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 33, taskName: 'Testing', startDate: new Date('02/20/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/21/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Critical', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 34, taskName: 'Bug fix', startDate: new Date('02/24/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/25/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'High', approved: false },
                        { taskID: 35, taskName: 'Customer review meeting', startDate: new Date('02/26/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), duration: 2, progress: '0', priority: 'Normal', approved: true },
                        { taskID: 36, taskName: 'Phase 3 complete', startDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), endDate: new Date('02/27/2017'), duration: 0, priority: 'Critical', approved: false },
                    ]
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { sampleData } from '../datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild('treegrid')
  public data: Object[];
  public foo: boolean;

  dropdown(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

  subtask(e){
    console.log(e);
    this.foo == false ? this.foo = true : this.foo = false;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = sampleData;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using safe navigation operator `?` in the template. Here is a working demo in [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cecpq)

```
<H1>Table</H1>

<table *ngFor="let datum of data;" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td class=""> </td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{{datum?.taskID}}</td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{{datum?.taskName}}</td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2  btn btn.primary" (click)="dropdown(datum)">...</td>
  </tr>
  <div *ngIf="datum.subtasks">
  <table  *ngFor="let subtask of datum.subtasks">
      <tr>
          <td class="">> </td>
          <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{{subtask?.taskID}}</td>
          <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{{substask?.taskName}}</td>
          <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 btn btn.primary" (click)="dropdown(subtask)">...</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: looking at your stack blitz, it seems the nested taskNames aren't populating.  (edit)The error is gone, but the the subtask task names aren't populating.  You can see the taskId populating still, though.  getting closer

Comment: @camelCase the problem seem to be using table inside table can show how the visual template should look so that i can change the html code to represent your view

Comment: I have since edited my markup to only have one table tag.  I'm still having the same issue.  take a look at my updated markup.  I also noticed having div tags in my table tags messed up a bunch of stuff too.  so what you said is true and needed to be removed.